# Chrome extension : Links collector

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

popup.js:

```
function GetUrls()
    {
    var fourmTabs = new Array();
    chrome.tabs.query({}, function (tabs) {
        for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
            fourmTabs[i] = tabs[i];
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < fourmTabs.length; i++) {
            if (fourmTabs[i] != null)
            {
            document.write("<b>" + fourmTabs[i].title + "</b>" + "<br/><a href='" + fourmTabs[i].url + "'>" + fourmTabs[i].url + "</a><br/><br/>");
             }  
            else {
                document.write("??" + i);
            }
        }
    });
    }
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", GetUrls());

    function OpenInNewTab(url )
    {
     var win=window.open(url, '_blank');
      win.focus();
    }
     //document.addEventListener('??', OpenInNewTab(??));
```

Now the new tab step ..How can I call OpenNewTab function with urls that are local variables in GetUrls function ? or is there any better idea ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you want. In any case, [`getSelected`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-getSelected) is deprecated in favor of [`query`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-query), so you should use that:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    chrome.tabs.query({
        // All tabs in current window
        currentWindow: true
    },
    function(tabs) {
        var olTag = document.createElement("ol");
        for (var i = 0, len = tabs.length; i < len; i++) {
            // Create a list-item for each tab
            var liTag = document.createElement("li");
            liTag.appendChild(document.createTextNode(tabs[i].url));
            olTag.appendChild(liTag);
        }
        document.body.appendChild(olTag);
    });
});
```

This code lists the URLs of all tabs you have open, like so:

```
These are links you open:

    1. http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20557596/edit
    2. chrome://extensions/
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the links?

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer is very useful.
I want: 
1-Open a URL in a new tab when clicking on it. 
2-Save a URL to the bookmarks.
Check the edit on question.

Comment: Why do you want to create multiple tabs at the same URL? And by the way, you can already do that in Chrome by right-clicking the tab and selecting Duplicate.

Comment: I mean URLs that i get from extension,open them in new tab when clicking on them.